# Magento 2 : get full file path of full size image currently assigned to product

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-images, image, gallery-image

I want to get the full file path of the full-size image currently assigned to a product so as to rename and upload it again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just for a single product?If your answer is yes Then I would suggest you to use simple MySQL query like `SELECT 'image' from 'catalog_product_entity' where SKU = "your-product-sku"`

Comment: unfortunately no, I have to write a script for updating image name of all the products